# Python Crash Course 9-15 Exercise

Tags: python

I have a problem with my logic. I'm currently reading python crash course, one of the exercises asks to model a lottery ticket and to see how many tries it took. The problem is I can leave it for days without winning....

```
import random


a_list = ('33','18','27','5','4','12')

winner_ticket = ('33','18','27')
run = 0 
while True:
    run += 1
    if random.sample(a_list,3) == winner_ticket:
        print(f"Your ticket is a winner with the numbers d{winner_ticket}")
        break

    if run > 50000:
            break
    else:
        print(f"This is try number: {run}")
```

Comment: It sounds like you're accurately modelling the lottery

Comment: Do you have a specific question? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic]. Have you done any debugging?

Answer (score 2):

`random.sample` returns a list. You are comparing a tuple.

This is `False`:

```
('33', '5', '4') == ['33', '5', '4']
```

Try testing with a list instead.

```
winner_ticket = ['33','18','27']
```

Comment: Yes, thanks now it works !. I've won my first lottery ticket haha.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly coursework so I'll provide some advice.

Your `winner_ticket` is a tuple. `random.sample()` returns a list. You cannot directly compare the two as they are not equal. You will have to check if each element is within the winning tuple.

Furthermore, you should note that the lists [1, 2, 3] does not equal the list [1, 3, 2]. `random.sample()` can return the list elements in any order. One way you can try to get past this is to sort the `winner_ticket` (after changing it to a list as a tuple is immutable) and sorting the `random.sample()`

If you follow the sorting method, then you can compare the two lists `winner_ticket` and `random.sample()` and get a valid result.

Comment: Yes , you are right. The reason i use random.sample() is to make it look like i've been trying those numbers and failed winning the actual lottery ticket. But yes you are right and thanks for a fast feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `random.sample()` returns a list, but `winner_ticket` is a tuple. So either make winner ticket a list:

```
winner_ticket = ['33','18','27']
```

...or cast `random.sample()` to a tuple:

```
if tuple(random.sample(a_list,3)) == winner_ticket:
```